# How to block direct access to html page

Tags: html

I have a sub html (template) `products.html`, that I included in my `index.html` page with JavaScript/jquery function .load()

Now the problem is products.html can be access directly if you type its url, and it gives a very ugly page alone, so I tried to redirect anyone who tries to access it to index.html using JS function `windows.location`. The problem with this method is, when my template is loaded in my main page, the js script fires, and it leads to refresh to the page. So is there another way to go about this !?

Comment: Make it with .htaccess and rules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a variable like `window.parentPage = true;`
in the index.html file.

In the products.html page make a check like so:

```
if(!window.parentPage)
{
    window.location.href = "YOUR REDIRECTION PAGE"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
<body onload="if (document.referrer == '') self.location='index.html';">
```

Comment: @party-ring The referrer property returns the URL of the document that loaded the current document. So say you visit _mywebsite.com_ and you click on products which takes you to _mywebsite.com/products.html/_ . The document referrer will be _mywebsite.com_ . But if you visit _mywebsite.com/products.html/_ directly then you do not have a referrer. You can read more here - [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp)

Comment: +1 for nice generic approach. Also note that I used this within document.ready which left the page faster than onload.