# How do I define a variable in my index.html file? (window.parentPage = true;)

Tags: javascript, html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43635720

On this answer, it says to define a variable (window.parentPage = true;) in the index.html page. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the variable using JavaScript. You can embed some JavaScript in the HTML file by encasing it in a `script` tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parentPage = true;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clearly realize your reason... what you want to achieve.

After that defining that to yourself:

**First option:**
You can store/save some data as stated on the link you added to your question inside a  tag, like that:

```
<script>
    var myLittleBox = "box content";
</script>
```

And access it later like:

```
<script>
    myLittleBox = myLittleBox + " extra content";
    console.log(myLittleBox);
    //this will print "box content extra content"
</script>
```

You need to use the  tag to access the javascript environment.

**Second option:**
You can save/store data with pure HTML using an  with type "hidden" to not show it on screen as an input box, and changing it's value, like that:

```
<input type="hidden" value="box content">
```

But this way you'll not be able to access the data directly without aid of javascript code, unless you send this input somewhere reachable as GET or POST within a  and recover it getting the respective GET or POST.

**Javascript variables:**

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Ex: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_variables

**HTML input:**

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

**HTML form handling:**

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

You're probably trying to understand the first option, but you question do not make that clear. Anyway, good studies.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do you will have to use JavaScript in order to access the variable. An orthodox way of doing it that is not mentioned yet is using an data-attribute inside the html and than you access it by JavaScript:

```js
const attributeName = 'data-parentPage';
const setup = () => {
 let parentPageBool = document.querySelector(`html[${attributeName}]`).getAttribute(attributeName);
  console.log(parentPageBool)
};
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<html data-parentPage="true">
  
</html>
```